# Does Photoshop CC have automatic upload function?

Tags: adobe, photoshop, creative-cloud

When I save image files in Creative Cloud folder, they are uploaded at Creative Cloud. Does it have other way?
Can Photoshop CC upload image files automatically to Creative Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

Thats why there is CC word.
Creative Cloud